# What is the best structure to separate all tables per client

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, data-structures, ef-code-first

For instance, i have these entities

```
Client : table

TransactionA : table
TransactionB : table
..
TransactionZ : table
```

**TransactionA** to **TransactionZ** table is referenced to **Client**

in database structure, i've been thinking of creating new table *TransactionA* for every new Client registered and has a schema with the **Client.Code** so it looks like **clientA.tbl_TransactionA**.

with this structure, i think my database would generate thousands of table depending on how many clients will register which i think that it is hard in maintenance if there's a modification in core.

I would like to ask for your opinion on the best approach on this matter, advantage and disadvantage.

**PS:**
I am using Entity Framework (code first), **MSSQL**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a table per client would not be a good idea on many levels. To pick one of the more obvious ones, using Entity Framework you would have to alter and recompile your code each time you wanted to add a client. You'd probably have to use reflection or to figure out which client `DbSet` to reference when seeking a transaction.

It isn't clear what has driven you to this design consideration, but it would seem obvious that the more reasonable model would be to have a Transactions table that had a foreign key / navigation property to the Client table. I assume there's some good but unstated reason why this would not suffice, though.